# a regular expression in preg_match that returns 3 matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My input is as below:

```
*test*
```

The output I want is content inside two asterisks (test).
My code is as below:

```
preg_match('/^(\*(.*)\*)$/','*test*',$matches);
```

Its output is:

```
 Array ( [0] => *test* [1] => *test* [2] => test )
```

The third one is the one I want. I know why it does this, but I don't know how to solve it. How to write an RE that returns just **test** nothing else.

Comment: Match 0 will always be there, since it is the match by the whole expression. Match 1 and 2 are the text captured by the 2 capturing groups in your regex. It is possible to write a regex that does what you want, but it unnecessarily reduce the readability of the regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh As I said **I know why it does this**. I want the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [look-ahead and look-behind assertions](http://php.net/regexp.reference.assertions):

```
/(?<=^\*).*(?=\*$)/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this by using explode function :

```
<?php $str = '*test*';
$str1 = explode('*',  $str);
echo $str1[1]; 
?>
```

Comment: Not what I want. It has similar problem to mine. It produces few items. I doesn't solve my problem. I want just one output otherwise mine works with no problem.